# How can we generate MCE(machine check errors)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, crash, kernel, kernel-module

As much I know that `mcelog` is used to check the memory errors in the hardware. I want to simulate the same case. I don't have any machine which is having the issue with hardware where I can simulate this case. Can anybody suggest me some simulator or any other way through which I can generate these errors. Because my main aim is to display the `Uncorrectable Memory errors`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tool [mce-inject](https://github.com/andikleen/mce-inject), but you'll need to load the `mce_inject` kernel module. This kernel module is available on Ubuntu 12.04 (the only system I have access to) and should be available on newer Ubuntus, as well.

First, you need to load the module:

```
$ sudo modprobe mce_inject
```

Next, you need to download the source for the `mce_inject` tool, install the dependencies, and compile it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/andikleen/mce-inject.git
$ sudo apt-get install flex bison
$ cd mce-inject
$ make
```

Next, you need to create a file that simulates the error you want. You should check the `mce-inject` man page (included in the source) for more information on the structure. You can find some examples in the `test/` directory in the [`mce-inject` source](

**Injecting a FATAL error can destabilize and crash the system; doing this is not recommended.**

Once you've decided which example file to use (or have created your own) you can inject it with `mce-inject`. For example, injecting the `test/corrected` example error included with `mce-inject`:

```
$ sudo ./mce-inject test/corrected
```

You can now check your logs and find that the error has been injected.

Comment: Thanks for your useful information. I am going to check the same on Red Hat Linux.

Comment: the only difference on redhat linux is `sudo yum install bison flex` instead of `sudo apt-get install bison flex`.  Let me know what else is needed to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I am using your method and it works, but the only thing that I can observe in both dmesg and messages logfiles are messages like this: [date] MCE exception done on CPU 0. Where else can I look to check the error with more details?

Comment: More details can be found in /var/log/mcelog if mcelog has been set up.